# Count ocurrences and show the last ocurrence in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
serie      number
-----      ------
A          1
A          2
A          3
A          5
B          1
B          3
```

I want to show a result like this

```
serie      ocurrences   last_number_value
-----      ----------   -----------------
A          4                          5
B          2                          3
```

I managed to get the ocurrences number with

`SELECT serie, number, COUNT(*) AS ocurrences FROM table_name GROUP BY serie`

But, how to show the last number too?

Comment: If the numbers always go up you can use `MAX(number)`

Comment: Hey, `MAX(number)` works. Please write your response so I can check it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the result your looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  serie varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  num int(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (serie, num) VALUES 
('A', 1),
('A', 2),
('A', 3),
('A', 5),
('B', 1),
('B', 3);
```

*If the row order matters:*

```
SELECT 
 a.serie,
 (SELECT count(*) FROM test WHERE serie=a.serie) as occurances,
 a.num
FROM
  test AS a
  LEFT JOIN test AS b on a.serie=b.serie AND a.num<b.num
  WHERE 
b.serie IS NULL;
```

*If the order or the rows do NOT matter:*

```
SELECT 
  a.serie,
  COUNT(*) AS occurances,
  MAX(a.num) AS last_number_value
FROM
  test AS a
GROUP BY a.serie;
```